# URLConnection resolving DNS even when using proxy

Tags: java, proxy, dns, tor, socks

I'm developing an application that has to connect through a SOCKS proxy (Tor). I've been able to successfully open a `Socket` and an `SSLSocket` connection through the proxy without any DNS requests to my default DNS servers (i.e. the proxy handled the DNS). The next thing I want to implement is Http which I would usually do using the `HttpURLConnection` class. I tried using `URL.openConnection(proxy)` which worked, but java was resolving the IP using my default DNS servers instead of letting the proxy handle DNS.

I tried creating my own `URLConnection`/`HttpURLConnection` implementation, but had no luck. I also looked at some other Http Client libraries, but had no luck with those either since most of them use the built-in `HttpURLConnection` class.

I've also looked into forcing the `HttpURLConnection` class to use a pre-connected socket for Http, thus I could open a socket like usual and let the proxy handle DNS before wrapping it with the `HttpURLConnection` class, but it looks like this isn't possible.

At this point I don't know how to solve this problem. All ideas are appreciated.

Here's the code I have right now (without any http support, just `Socket` and `SSLSocket`): https://github.com/tadejgasparovic/JTor

Thanks!